# Flutter: show dialogue with generate route

Tags: flutter, showdialog, flutter-routes

I have a page in my app where I give a file as a parameter but if the file is too large then I would like to stay at the same screen and with a warning message displayed using `showDialogue`. Since there are many entry points to this screen I am using generatedRoutes to check if the file will be rejected.

This check (the if statement) works at the moment , however, I have no idea how to stay on the screen and show the error. This is what I have so far:

```
  Route<dynamic>? generateRoute(RouteSettings settings, BuildContext context) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case homePage:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage());

      case previewFilePage:
        var file = settings.arguments as FileModel;

        if (file.size > kMaxFileBytes) {
          // What I want to do but doesnt work
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return PopUpDialogue(
                  message: Text("File is too large"),
                );
              }
           );
           
          break;
        } else {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PreviewFilePage(
              file: file,
            ),
          );
        }

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage());
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Is there a way to do this or will I have to add these error messages manually on each entry page? Also I know I could create an error page and direct to it if the check fails but I would much better prefer to have a dialogue show up instead.

Thanks!

Comment: why are not doing this inside PreviewFilePage?

Comment: I would like to stop the user before entering the page, otherwise its a bit ugly to me how you go to a new page only to have an error show up that redirects you back

Comment: checking this kind of thing is one of states  of that page.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without having a visual transition of going to a new page?

Comment: From my point of view, I don't think so.